# Script on boot up is not updating between calls

Tags: boot, script, bash

I wrote a simple script in order to log the date and time of every Pi boot into a text file.  I placed the script into /etc/rc.local in order to have it execute on boot.

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/sh

FILEPATH=/home/pi/bootups.txt
DATE=$(date +"%m.%d.%y")
TIME=$(date +"%l:%M %P")

$(echo $DATE'\t'$TIME >> $FILEPATH)
```

I call the script in rc.local using this line:

```
/home/pi/countbootup.sh
```

After every Pi boot, the DATE and TIME variable never change.  I end up with a text file looking like:

```
07.12.16    11:17pm
07.12.16    11:17pm
07.12.16    11:17pm
```

When I call the script on my own, the DATE and TIME update as expected.

Comment: Because the clock hasn't yet synchronized with an NTP server, the Pi does not have a real time clock. You could add one or wait for an NTP sync before logging the time.

Comment: That makes complete sense.  Is there any way to tell when the NTP has been synced, or to ensure that the script is called after that?

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18642/how-to-check-if-ntpd-updates-machines-time-successfully-using-shell